# Given A and B two fixed points on the circle find the locus of the orthocenter of triangle ABC where C is a mobile point on the circle.

Tags: geometry

First we have to find the locus and then we have to prove double inclusion.

Please help me !

Answer (score 1):

Due to Euler's theorem, the circumcenter, orthocenter and centroid of a triangle are always collinear. Moreover, $HG=2\cdot GO$ holds. This means that if we take the circumcenter $O$ as the origin of $\mathbb{R}^2$, the vector identities
$$ G = \frac{A+B+C}{3},\qquad H=A+B+C $$
hold. This means that if $A,B$ stay fixed while $C$ runs over the circumcircle $\Gamma$, $H$ describes a circle congruent to $\Gamma$ having $A+B$ as center. The converse implication is straightforward since $\{A,B,C,H\}$ is an orthocentric system, giving that $C$ is the orthocenter of $ABH$.

Comment: As an alternative you can simply prove that the symmetric of the orthocenter with respect to a side of a triangle $ABC$ always lie on the circumcircle of $ABC$.

Comment: but how i do A+B ? Because A and B are points

Comment: we know that the circle is in plan

Comment: $A+B$ as a vector sum, when the circumcenter $O$ is the origin, is just the symmetric of $O$ with respect to the midpoint of $AB$ due to the parallelogram law.

Comment: So $H$ belongs to a circle that is just the symmetric of the circumcircle of $ABC$ with respect to the $AB$-side.